# Bulk Email Validator

Tags: php, email, smtp, dns, email-validation

I wish to either make use of a freely available email validator (software, script or online service). If this does not exist, are there some free PHP classes that I can make use of to validate email addresses?

I have about 100 emails and before I send to these emails I would like to check their validity. I don't want my server to be blacklisted because of bounce backs.

Please note, I am not looking for just a a syntax checker. I am talking about DNS and SMTP validation.

The ideal solution would be a pHP script or the like that I can setup locally or on my server.

Thanks all for any help

Comment: What reason do you have to believe that these emails are invalid?  You should only be sending mail to people who have given you permission to send them mail; in that case, they would have given you a valid email address already.

Comment: A SMTP socket connection checking whether a `RCPT TO` is agreed to (allow for greylisting, understand proxy mailservers may agree to any emailaddress with a proper domain), and/or `VERP` on the receiving server to immediately unsubscribe bouncemails are easily created. This is a programmers site after all ;)

Comment: they coudlve typed their email wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try running gethostbyname() on whatever is after the @ and if it doesnt return an IP, its not a valid DNS

Comment: Interesting. Is there something this straight forward for SMTP validation in PHP?

Comment: I would assume u could just do the same thing.
Check this out too, idk how good it is, but it looked cool
http://code.google.com/p/php-smtp-email-validation/